# Why is MySQL not using this index with a GROUP BY query?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have this big table (ca million records) and I'm trying to retrieve the last record of each type.

The table, the index and the query are very simple, and the fact that MySQL is not using the index means I must be overlooking something.

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `MyTable001` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TypeField` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Value` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `AnotherField1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_MyTable001_TypeField` (`TypeField`),
  KEY `idx_MyTable001_Timestamp` (`Timestamp`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Show Index gives this:

```
+------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name                 | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| MyTable001 |          0 | PRIMARY                  |            1 | id          | A         |      626141 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| MyTable001 |          1 | idx_MyTable001_TypeField |            1 | TypeField   | A         |         458 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| MyTable001 |          1 | idx_MyTable001_Timestamp |            1 | Timestamp   | A         |      156535 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

But when I execute EXPLAIN for the following query:

```
SELECT   *
FROM    MyTable001
GROUP BY TypeField
ORDER BY id DESC
```

The result is this:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | MyTable001 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 626141 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

Why won't MySQL use `idx_MyTable001_TypeField`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That query doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: As said in the question, "I'm trying to retrieve the last record of each type."

Comment: If you group by TypeField, it will need to look at every TypeField in every row selected. Since it will need to look at every TypeField, there's no point in using an index (it will actually be slower), so it does a full table scan.

Comment: Your response wasn't clear but I think I understand now: The fact that I'm grouping by TypeField doesn't mean that the rows with a specific TypeField are not gonna be read. They will still be read, and therefore a full table scan will be necessary. Is that correct?

Comment: In short, if you want all typefields, there's no need to use the index, because you want them all anyway (= full table scan). Indices are good for selectings one or a few matching possibilities. They work well in where clauses and joins, but not in group by and order by

Comment: If you use "group by" the fields you are selecting need to use an agregate function, otherwise you will get pretty much random data for the fields that don;t appear in the "group by" clause. Group by does not necessarily select complete records!

Comment: @Sam, the index can be used with group by, but it can be used when the other fields are also read (see my own answer)

Comment: @Jaydee, you are correct, I'll try Joachim Isaksson's or fancyPants' answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the content of the fields not in the group by are still being inspected. Therefore, all rows must be read, and it's better to do a full table scan. This is clearly seen with the following examples:

`SELECT TypeField, COUNT(*) FROM MyTable001 GROUP BY TypeField` uses the index.

`SELECT TypeField, COUNT(id) FROM MyTable001 GROUP BY TypeField` does not.

The original query was incorrect. The correct query is:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM  MyTable001 l
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) m_id
    FROM MyTable001 l
    GROUP BY l.TypeField) l_id ON l_id.m_id = l.id;
```

It takes 260ms in a table with 630k records. Joachim Isaksson's and fancyPants' alternatives took several minutes in my tests.

Comment: Yes, like I said in my answer one should try different alternatives to queries. Good you found a solution, still something is strange here. Your two count() queries should both use an index. Your explanation is not entirely correct. The difference between the two queries is, that `COUNT(*)` considers all rows, whereas `COUNT(id)` only considers `NOT NULL` rows. But since you use `id` which is primary key and `NOT NULL` and MySQL should know this very well, both queries should use the index.

Comment: I agree MySQL should use the index, however it does not (at least the EXPLAIN query says it doesn't).